# How to find prime numbers between 0 - 100 in javascript without using built in funcitions ? both count of primes numbers and numbers itself

Tags: javascript, numbers, primes

I am trying to find the prime numbers from 1-n (say n=100). Without using built in functions. I have thought about it, and I am not sure how to find them. I tried using two for loops and a count variable to know the count of prime numbers between 1-n. And I also want print these numbers on console.

```
function countPrimes(num){
  let count=0
  let primeCount=0;
  let i,j
  for(j=2;j<=num;j++)
  {
  for( i=2;i<=j;i++)
  {
    if(j%i==0)
    count++
  }

  if(count==2){
    primeCount++;
  }
  count=0



  }
  return primeCount;
}

console.log(countPrimes(100));
```

I try to run the above code but getting nothing in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
function countPrimes(num){
  let count = 0;
  for(let i = 2; i <= num; i++){
    let isPrime = true;
    for(let j = 2; j < i; j++){
      if(i % j == 0){
        isPrime = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(isPrime){
      count++;
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(countPrimes(100));
```

Comment: keep in mind as well that there's no point in checking for divisors greater than the square root of i, so you can set the termination condition of the inner loop to make your code run more than twice as fast pretty easily

Answer (score 0):

Every number is divided by 1 so we will start i loop from 2

```js
function countPrimes(num){
  let count = 0;
  for(let i = 2; i <= num; i++){
    let prime = true;
    for(let j = 2; j < i; j++){
      if(i % j == 0){
        prime = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(prime){
      count++;
      console.log("Prime number", i);
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log("total Prime numbers",countPrimes(100));
```

Comment: yes! got it thanks for your timely response

Comment: If this solution solved your problem, please upvote it and mark as accepted answer